# Is there a way to loop function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, ssms, database-cursor

I'm trying to write queries that can loop new columns to selected number, such as 100 or 200 new columns, which use data from the previously created columns.

I have data like below:

```
IF NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'test' AND xtype = 'U'
) 
CREATE TABLE test 
(
    [id] INT,
    [a] NUMERIC(3, 2),
    [b] NUMERIC(3, 2)
);

INSERT INTO test 
VALUES (1, 0.1, 0.7),
       (2, 0.5, 0.5),
       (3, 0.5, 0.3),
       (4, 0.6, 0.5),
       (5, 0.5, 0.5),
       (6, 0.5, 0.67),
       (7, 0.5, 0.5),
       (8, 0.46, 0.5),
       (9, 0.5, 0.5),
       (10, 0.37, 0.52),
       (11, 0.37, 0.37),
       (12, 0.28, 0.2);
```

I have id, a, and b as input, and I want to create new columns as c c = a+b, then d = a+b+c and so on, to even 100 or 200 new columns.

I could use queries like the one below, but if I need 100 columns, it will take forever to write.

```
select 
    t.*,
    t.a + t.b + t.c d
from
    (select 
         *, 
         a + b c 
     from test) t;
```

I know that SQL is not good at loops, but I still want to try if it even possible.Thank you.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment where you're required to use a loop, or is this a problem that you need a solution for, and you think a loop is that solution?

Comment: You don't need a loop here you need dynamic SQL, although I can't fathom the purpose of such a query.

Comment: Having 100 or 200 columns in a table is a clear indication that the design went totally the wrong direction.

Comment: It is for one of my projects in which I have used python in this case, but I still want to try if SQL is possible.

Comment: for that kind of logic you can use procedures, which can loop and have flow control

Comment: Are you happy that you can never exceed the max row size with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

The specifics of your problem indicate the database design is terrible, you'd never want to sum across columns like that. But your question about whether in SQL you can tell it to sort of write itself so that it'll save you from typing it all out, is generally no.

In some cases, database systems will support something like `EXCEPT` (or since Snowflake likes to be different, `EXCLUDE`)

That is helpful because you can `SELECT * EXCEPT col1` which is sort of what you're looking for, though you're wanting to do that with a `SUM`.

In general, no the language does not support such things. You might get lucky in some cases, where an RDBMS adds a helpful function for something that lots of users want to do (like in the case of EXCEPT)

Therefore, if you really want to do it, you have to look outside of SQL and build it yourself. For me personally, I run my SQL through a jinja engine that will parse out the SQL for me.

I actually have a custom wrapper that does the exact thing you want:

```
SELECT *,
       ({{ variables | join(' + ') }}) AS SUM_OF_ALL
FROM {{ source_table }}
```

This is essentially a function that I have to pass a list of column names into it - so if I had 200 it would still be annoying. However using macros and other things it is definitely possible, to have it dynamically find all the column names so they don't have to be declared explicitly.

TL;DR -  no, not possible without going outside of SQL.

Comment: Of course it's possible in SQL

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```sql
IF NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT  * FROM  sysobjects WHERE    name = 'test' AND xtype = 'U'
) 
CREATE TABLE test 
(
    [id] INT,
    [a] NUMERIC(3, 2),
    [b] NUMERIC(3, 2)
);

INSERT INTO test 
VALUES (1, 0.1, 0.7),
       (2, 0.5, 0.5),
       (3, 0.5, 0.3),
       (4, 0.6, 0.5),
       (5, 0.5, 0.5),
       (6, 0.5, 0.67),
       (7, 0.5, 0.5),
       (8, 0.46, 0.5),
       (9, 0.5, 0.5),
       (10, 0.37, 0.52),
       (11, 0.37, 0.37),
       (12, 0.28, 0.2);

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = 'select t.*'

;WITH cte AS (
SELECT  TOP 100 row_number() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT  NULL)) AS cnt
FROM    sys.objects so CROSS JOIN sys.columns sc
)
SELECT  @sql = @sql + '
, 0' + '+ (t.a + t.b) * (POWER(2.0, ' + CAST(c.cnt  as varchar(30)) + '-1))  as c' + cast(c.cnt AS varchar(300))
FROM    cte c

SELECT  @sql = @sql + ' from test t'
SELECT  @sql
EXEC    (@sql)
```

EDIT:
This code loops 100 columns or so and generate sums for previous column in a new column.
The sums get pretty big after a while. Maybe i'm doing something wrong but not sure :)

Comment: wow many thanks! However u are right until c3 which i mean c3 = a+b+c1+c2 then c4 = a+b+c1+c2+c3 and so on

Comment: yeah, it was a bit more tricky, let's see

Comment: Wow exactly what I mean. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi, what if I make a new table with rule c1=a, then c2 =a* (1-c1), c3=a*(1-c2) and so on? Is it possible?

Comment: It should be. I kinda cheated in my code because the sums could be converted to multiplication but I guess there should be a good formula to solve even för a * (1 - c1). Feel free to adapt my code to your needs :)